# SQL - How to have multiple queries in a statement without a loop or union all

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I didn't have room to make the title more descriptive, sorry, but this is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am making a data table for a Google Histogram chart on a web page.  I am looking at customer and invoice data, and I want to get a snapshot of the customer status for each week of a previous time period (week, month, quarter, year).  I know what my SELECT statement should be for a week, and I can do it using UNION ALL, but that seems like a lot of code to maintain if I want each week for the past three years.  There will be other filters which I have removed for this example (MS SQL 2008):

```
    SELECT COUNT(distinct customer.AccountNumber)
    FROM Datahub..InvoiceHold invoice 
        INNER JOIN Datahub..CustomerBase as customer ON invoice.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber
        INNER JOIN Datahub..OrderHold as orders ON invoice.AccountNumber = orders.AccountNumber
    WHERE customer.CoNo = '003' 
        AND customer.CustomerStartDate <= GETDATE() - 7
        AND invoice.InvoiceDate > GETDATE() - 7
        AND orders.OrderDate > GETDATE() - 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(distinct customer.AccountNumber)
    FROM Datahub..InvoiceHold invoice 
        INNER JOIN Datahub..CustomerBase as customer ON invoice.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber
        INNER JOIN Datahub..OrderHold as orders ON invoice.AccountNumber = orders.AccountNumber
    WHERE customer.CoNo = '003' 
        AND customer.CustomerStartDate <= GETDATE() - 14
        AND invoice.InvoiceDate > GETDATE() - 14
        AND orders.OrderDate > GETDATE() - 14
    UNION ALL........And so on
```

I have thought about dynamically writing the SQL string in my calling code, and I can easily do a for loop there and concatenate a query string which I send to MS SQL 2008.  But if I want to do this in a stored procedure, how would I narrow this down to a single statement?  I have read that using loops in SQL is a no-no except for a narrow range of situations, and I don't understand using cursors.  It seems like this should be easy but I am not a SQL guy.

**EDIT**
I tried the solutions presented, and did not get the kind of performance I was looking for, oddly enough.  It was taking 7 minutes or more.  I am not sure why.  Anyways, I ended up doing some filtering on the data and pulling it into memory, and then using LINQ on the dataTable and going from there.  It may not be pretty, but it only takes about 20 seconds.

Thank you very much for the replies!

Comment: Why not store the results of the query in a temp table? You can create a `WHILE` loop for the individual weeks, and just keep `INSERT`ing the values in the table.

Comment: You can add OVER to your count and make them "window functions". Then you'd just need one query with a lot of counts, which you can build dynamic. However I would likely look into just pre calculating each week and store it in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solutions presented, and did not get the kind of performance I was looking for, oddly enough.  It was taking 7 minutes or more.  I am not sure why.  Anyways, I ended up doing some filtering on the data and pulling it into memory, and then using LINQ on the dataTable and going from there.  It may not be pretty, but it only takes about 20 seconds.  Here is my code if anyone ever wants to do something similar:

```
public IList<object[]> GetBarChartData(string timeframe, string channel, string unit, string division)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<CustomerClass> myList = new List<CustomerClass>();
        List<object[]> retVal = new List<object[]>();
        CustomerClass myClass = new CustomerClass();

        string marketChannel = (channel == "ALL MARKET CHANNELS" ? string.Empty : "AND customer.MarketChannelDescription = '" + channel + "' ");
        string businessUnit = (unit == "ALL BUSINESS UNITS" ? string.Empty : "AND customer.BusinessUnitDescription = '" + unit + "' ");

        using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionManager.DataHubConnection())
        {
            string sql = "SELECT customer.AccountNumber "
                    + ", customer.CustomerStartDate "
                    + ", MAX(invoice.InvoiceDate) as LastInvoice "
                    + ", MAX(orders.OrderDate) AS LastOrder "
                + "FROM Datahub..InvoiceHold as invoice "
                    + "INNER JOIN Datahub..CustomerBase as customer ON invoice.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber "
                    + "INNER JOIN Datahub..OrderHold as orders ON invoice.AccountNumber = orders.AccountNumber "
                + "WHERE customer.CoNo = '003' "
                    + "AND customer.CustomerStartDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 1095 AND GETDATE() "
                    + marketChannel
                    + businessUnit
                + "GROUP BY customer.AccountNumber, customer.CustomerStartDate "
                + "ORDER BY LastInvoice ";

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }

        string foo = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            myClass = new CustomerClass();
            myClass.AccountNumber = row["AccountNumber"].ToString();
            myClass.CustomerStartDate = row["CustomerStartDate"] == DBNull.Value ? new DateTime(1900,1,1) : Convert.ToDateTime(row["CustomerStartDate"]);
            myClass.LastInvoiceDate = row["LastInvoice"] == DBNull.Value ? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) : Convert.ToDateTime(row["LastInvoice"]);
            myClass.LastOrderDate = row["LastOrder"] == DBNull.Value ? "1-1-1900" : Convert.ToDateTime(row["LastOrder"]).ToString("d");
            myList.Add(myClass);
        }

        // Use LINQ to break this data into series and then write string

        // How many weeks do we need
        int weeks = 1;
        switch (timeframe)
        {
            case "Last Year":
                weeks = 104;
                break;
            case "This Year":
                weeks = 52;
                break;
            case "Last Quarter":
                weeks = 26;
                break;
            case "This Quarter":
                weeks = 13;
                break;
            case "Last Month":
                weeks = 8;
                break;
            case "This Month":
                weeks = 4;
                break;
            case "Last Week":
                weeks = 2;
                break;
            case "This Week":
                weeks = 1;
                break;
        }


        object[] myArray = { "Class", "Lost", "Active", "Prospect" };
        retVal.Add(myArray);


        for (int i = 1; i <= weeks; i++)
        {
            var dateOffset = -(i * 7);
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(dateOffset);

            var prospect =
                from c in myList
                where c.CustomerStartDate <= date
                    && c.LastInvoiceDate > date
                    && c.LastOrderDate > date
                select c;
            var prospectCount = prospect.Count();

            var active =
                from c in myList
                where c.CustomerStartDate <= date
                    && c.LastInvoiceDate >= date.AddDays(-365)
                select c;
            var activeCount = active.Count();

            var lost =
                from c in myList
                where c.CustomerStartDate <= date
                    && c.LastInvoiceDate <= date.AddDays(-365)
                    && c.LastInvoiceDate >= date.AddDays(-730)
                select c;
            var lostCount = lost.Count();

            myArray = new object[] { i, lostCount, activeCount, prospectCount };
            retVal.Add(myArray);

        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to create a temp table of however many weeks you want to go back and use a group by to partition your data.

This will make the temp table with the week numbers (in this example it makes weeks 1 - 150)

```
declare @digits table 
(
    digit int
)
insert into @digits values (1)
insert into @digits values (2)
insert into @digits values (3)
insert into @digits values (4)
insert into @digits values (5)
insert into @digits values (6)
insert into @digits values (7)
insert into @digits values (8)
insert into @digits values (9)
insert into @digits values (0)

declare @weeks table
(
    weekNumber int
)
insert into @weeks
select a.digit * 100 + b.digit * 10 + c.digit
from @digits a
cross join @digits b
cross join @digits c
where a.digit * 100 + b.digit * 10 + c.digit <= 150
and a.digit * 100 + b.digit * 10 + c.digit > 0
```

Then you would do something like this in your query:

```
SELECT w.weekNumber, COUNT(distinct customer.AccountNumber)
FROM Datahub..InvoiceHold invoice 
    INNER JOIN Datahub..CustomerBase as customer ON invoice.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber
    INNER JOIN Datahub..OrderHold as orders ON invoice.AccountNumber = orders.AccountNumber
    INNER JOIN @weeks w ON customer.CustomerStartDate <= DATEADD(dd, -(w.weekNumber * 7), GetDate())
                AND invoice.InvoiceDate > DATEADD(dd, -(w.weekNumber * 7), GetDate())
                AND orders.OrderDate > DATEADD(dd, -(w.weekNumber * 7), GetDate())
WHERE customer.CoNo = '003' 
GROUP BY w.weekNumber
ORDER BY w.weekNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a table with the magic numbers. In Postgres, you can generate a pseudo-table with `generate_series`.

```
 SELECT gs, COUNT(distinct customer.AccountNumber)
 FROM Datahub..InvoiceHold invoice 
    INNER JOIN Datahub..CustomerBase as customer 
    ON invoice.AccountNumber = customer.AccountNumber
    INNER JOIN Datahub..OrderHold as orders 
    ON invoice.AccountNumber = orders.AccountNumber
    JOIN generate_series(1, 10) AS gs /* 10?? no on clause, cross join */
WHERE customer.CoNo = '003' 
    AND customer.CustomerStartDate <= GETDATE() - 7*gs
    AND invoice.InvoiceDate > GETDATE() - 7*gs
    AND orders.OrderDate > GETDATE() - 7*gs
ORDER BY 1,2 /* column numbers */;
```

If SQL Server doesn't have this, just make a table with 1 to 10 (or whatever) and cross join to that.